# html 5 video seek structure

Tags: html, html5-video, seek

Can anyone explain me how bowsers seek html5 videos? On flash it uses `start` pamaterer to seek videos. Example: `video.mp4?start=115.50` but on html5 videos (youtube videos) this is not working. So what parameter used to seek videos on html5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something that is called [Media Fragments](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/). Using this technique your URL could look something like this:

```
video.mp4#t=115.50
```

But this isn't fully supported. I think Chrome and Firefox have partial support this. As a workaround you can render a small JS inline script, which starts the video at your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can jump to a specific time in seconds using JavaScript:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.currentTime = 18;
```

See [MDN "HTMLMediaElement"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/s6dkZ/)

Comment: But i am using PHP. Php is a serverside

Comment: You didn't mention this nor tagged the question. And what do you want to achieve actually if this is not want you're looking for?